for each $k\geq 4$ find a $k$-connected graph $G\neq K_{k+1}$ such that $\forall e\in E, \kappa(G/e)=k-1$.
The background is Bondy&Murty GTM244 Graph Theory p.212

Exercise 9.1.10
a) Show that if $G$ is a $k$-connected graph and $e$ is any edge of $G$, then $G / e$ is $(k − 1)$-connected.
b) For each $k \geq 4$, find a $k$-connected graph $G \neq K_{k+1}$ such that $\kappa(G / e) = k −1$, for every edge $e$ of $G$.

I have solved (a) and I can't find a graph satisfying conditions for (b). In fact if $\kappa(G/e)<k$ then $\kappa(G)<k+1$ (according to (a)), so the graph what we will find must have $\kappa(G)=k$. Complete graphs are not allowed, and $K_{k,k}$ does not satisfy conditions, so I have no idea about it.
Any hints or suggestion welcome.

Why doesn't $K_{k,k}$ satisfy the conditions?

@MishaLavrov Because that $\kappa(K_{k,k}/e)=k$. remove any $k-1$ vertices will not disconnect it.

It seems to me that a $k-$regular graph would work? It has vertex connectivity $k$ (why?). If we remove an edge, then a vertex of that edge has $k-1$ neighbors, so if we remove those then the vertex is isolated.

@CalvinLin but it's edge contract, not remove

(In my case, also, what I was missing was that you're contracting and not removing an edge. Edge contractions are not very common, so it's easy to read your question and confuse $G/e$ with $G\setminus e$.)

The easiest way to ensure that the connectivity goes down to $k-1$ is to make sure that the minimum degree goes down to $k-1$, no matter which edge we contract. For this to happen, the edge we contract must be between two neighbors of some vertex of degree $k$. So it would suffice to find a $k$-connected, $k$-regular graph where each edge is part of a triangle.
Most dense $k$-regular graphs would work. To give a concrete example, take the graph $\overline{C_{k+3}}$: the complement of a $(k+3)$-cycle. This has the property we want as soon as $k\ge 4$.
